# Модификация файла формата ELF

Tags: elf, arm

Подскажите какие-то готовые средства(программы, утилиты, библиотеки программирования для любых ОС и средств разработки) помогающие модифицировать исполняемые файлы формата ELF. Хочу обратить внимание, что меня интересует формат не исполнимых файлов ELF для Linux, а общий ELF стандарт, конкретнее формат для микроконтроллеров ARM Cortex-M4.
Заранее спасибо всем ответившим.

Comment: Hiew в коммерческой версии вроде умеет ELF.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=265597